# phpmyadmin problem

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-5.3

can anyone solve this problem as per new to php

i have jsut installed wampsever 2.1 i am getting this error

my opertating system is windows 7 64 bit

phpmyadmin #2002 - the server is not responding (or the local mysql server's socket is not correctly configured)

Comment: Is your mysql server really running? If so on the right ip/port?

Comment: how to check it if its running or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty much self-explanatory: your MySQL configuration doesn't match that of php and/or phpmyadmin, or mysql isn't running.

You should do the following:

1. Make sure MySQL is running
2. Check phpinfo() for parameters of mysql extension
3. Check that config.inc.php in phpmyadmin has proper configuration directives